# Ambiguous overload accessing argument-less template functions with variadic parameters

Tags: c++, templates, boost, overloading, ambiguity

Yeah, the title can scare babies, but it's actually quite straightforward.

I am trying to store a function pointer to a specialized template function, namely boost::make_shared (boost 1.41), as illustrated:

```
boost::shared_ptr<int> (*pt2Function)() = boost::make_shared<int>;
```

However, it won't compile (GCC 4.4.1) due to the fact that boost::make_shared has the following two specializations which the compiler can't tell apart in this context:

```
template< class T > boost::shared_ptr< T > make_shared()
...
template< class T, class... Args > boost::shared_ptr< T > make_shared( Args && ... args )
```

The error, for reference:

```
In function ‘int main()’:
error: converting overloaded function ‘make_shared’ to type ‘class boost::shared_ptr<int> (*)()’ is ambiguous
boost/smart_ptr/make_shared.hpp:100: error: candidates are: boost::shared_ptr<X> boost::make_shared() [with T = int]
boost/smart_ptr/make_shared.hpp:138: error:                 boost::shared_ptr<X> boost::make_shared(Args&& ...) [with T = int, Args = ]
```

If I comment out the non-variadic variation, the code compiles fine.

Does anyone know the proper syntax for resolving the ambiguity between two argument-less functions like this?

Comment: What exact boost version are you using?

Comment: Boost version 1.41. Added it to the question.

Comment: Ok, if nobody else does so in the meantime i'll open a ticket after work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Variadic template arguments mean you take *0..n* template arguments, thus both your versions are matches.
You could resolve the ambiguity by adding another template parameter to the second version, so that it takes *1..n* arguments.
Something like this should work:

```
template< class T, class Arg1, class... Args > 
boost::shared_ptr< T > make_shared(Arg1&& arg1, Args && ... args )
```

But as UncleBens correctly pointed out, you don't even need two versions. The following should be enough in your case:

```
template< class T, class... Args > 
boost::shared_ptr<T> make_shared(Args && ... args );
```

If you use only one template argument (i.e. `T`), you get the 0-argument version of `make_shared()`.

Comment: It seems unclear to me, why the first overload is needed in the first place - one can "forward" zero arguments just as well?

Comment: Of course. However, these functions come from (a newer version of) the boost library. Perhaps they should be informed of the glitch?

Comment: Ok, so there isn't any "proper" way to do this. There is a hint in the boost headers as to why they have this stuff btw:
"// Zero-argument versions // Used even when variadic templates are available because of the new T() vs new T issue"

Well, if nothing else, the forwarding approach will suit my needs. It's not all that pretty. It makes my code depend on variadic parameters capabilities (decreasing portability slightly), but I can live with that. It'll do for now.

Comment: BTW, I can't quite figure out how to actually use this answer to solve my problem. Just to be sure, is the suggestion that I modify the boost headers?

Comment: Yep, until they fix it you have to either fix it in the header or write your own wrapper. With the comment you mention you should use the first solution i proposed.

Comment: ... and i see no way to select the first version unambigiously, so wrapping probably won't work :/

Comment: Thanks for the effort. Confirming that it can't be done is useful enough by itself. And in the meanwhile I found out a way to accomplish my goals without using boost::make_shared at all :)

Comment: I believe in actual C++0x, this should resolve to the first overload, because the first template is more specialized than the second. (using the template specializations function type, we deduce `shared_ptr<T>()` against `shared_ptr<T>(U...)`. Deduction for each of the types in `U...` against `()` (empty list) will fail, and deduction of `<T>` in the return type will succeed in both directions, and `()` against `(U...)` will succeed (with U being empty). Thus the first template is at least as specialized for each type, and more specialized for `()`, thus it's more specialized as a result).

Comment: Interesting, i'll have to look that up. So... this seems to have been a g++ bug then?

Comment: @gf, yes looks like it was a GCC bug.