# Ambiguous overload on argument-less variadic templates

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates, template-meta-programming

Related:

- [Ambiguous overload accessing argument-less template functions with variadic parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2109191/ambiguous-overload-accessing-argument-less-template-functions-with-variadic-para)
- [Simple variadic template function can't instantinate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7108161/simple-variadic-template-function-cant-instantinate)
- [Why is this variadic function ambiguous?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7109420/why-is-this-variadic-function-ambiguous)

---

Consider this pair of variadic templates:

```
template<typename Dummy>
bool All(Param& c) {
    return true;
}

template<typename Dummy, Func* f, Func* ...rest>
bool All(Param& c) {
    return f(c) && All<Dummy, rest...>(c);
}
```

This works and compiles. However, how to write it without the first template parameter?

Sounds trivial? Well, that's what I thought. :-) Let's consider some ideas.

### Idea #1:

```
template<Func* f, Func* ...rest>
bool All(Param& c) {
    return f(c) && All<rest...>(c);
}
template<>
bool All(Param& c) {
    return true;
}
```

Won't work... When I attempted this I had specialization in mind, but on the second thought that's not how it works.

In the original example I created two different templates of overloads, first taking 1 template parameter and second taking 2 or more. No ambiguities and no specialization involved. **am I getting it right?**

### Idea #2:

```
bool All(Param& c) {
    return true;
}

template<Func* f, Func* ...rest>
bool All(Param& c) {
    return f(c) && All<rest...>(c);
}
```

Won't work obviously, `All<rest...>` with `rest...` being empty won't expand to a call to a non-template function.

### Idea #3:

Let's rebuild the solution a bit.

```
template<Func* f>
bool All(Param& c) {
    return f(c);
}

template<Func* f, Func* ...rest>
bool All(Param& c) {
    return f(c) && All<rest...>(c);
}
```

This one is a no-go, because All(c) would be ambiguous. Hence I need to have a 0-arg case and a >0-arg case... Or what about a 1-arg case and a >1-arg case?

**Idea #3.5:**

```
template<Func* f>
bool All(Param& c) {
    return f(c);
}

template<Func* f, Func* f2, Func* ...rest>
bool All(Param& c) {
    return f(c) && All<f2, rest...>(c);
}
```

Yup, works, but contains copypasta (simple in this case but might be bigger!), hence I'd say it's no better than what I've started with. Just another workaround.

### Idea #4:

Let's try #1 but with classes instead of functions.

```
template<Func* f, Func* ...rest>
struct All {
    static bool func(Param& c) {
        return f(c) && All<rest...>(c);
    }
};
template<>
struct All {
    static bool func(Param& c) {
        return true;
    }
};
```

This looks promising since I can specialize classes. But hey, what is it?

> sorry, unimplemented: cannot expand 'rest ...' into a fixed-length argument list

Wasn't this a GCC 4.4 thing? I'm on MinGW GCC 4.6.1 (tdm-1).

---

Anyway, should I think that I cannot do such an elementary thing in a *straightforward* way? Is it required to use the workaround with an additional dummy template parameter to accomplish this task?

Or is there a simple, correct **variant to specify the zero-argument case**, which would work?

Comment: All of your subsequent ideas also have two classes/overloads/specializations.. What are you attempting to gain here?

Comment: Your Idea #3.5 has my vote.  It is what I would've put in an answer if you hadn't written it up yourself.  And if I'm not mistaken, there is some debate as to whether #3 is ambiguous or not.  I'm not sure where the dust settled on that one, or if it has even settled yet.  And it is because of that dust I prefer to just side-step the ambiguity issue and go with #3.5.

Comment: What Howard said. +1 for the effort put into the question

Comment: @Kos: I might misunderstand the question though, does [this](http://ideone.com/DpzNA) meet the objective?

Comment: @IseWisteria, that's exactly what I've been looking for; please post as answer so that you can be credited.

Comment: @Kos: Thanks! Please allow me a minute to write.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this question's case, since template parameters are non-type,
if we prepare a function with default template argument like the
following, `Dummy` parameter can be saved:

```
template<typename = void>
bool All(Param& c) {
    return true;
}

template<Func* f, Func* ...rest>
bool All(Param& c) {
    return f(c) && All<rest...>(c);
}
```

However, I'm not sure this is always applicable.
For more general case, `std::enable_if` or similar dispatch might be needed
(this will make the code a little lengthy though).

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your question is similar to this one:
[Compilation Error on Recursive Variadic Template Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5035889/compilation-error-on-recursive-variadic-template-function)

There are two answers there that should work; one that is your #3.5 and the second is one you didnt have.