# Passing functions as variadic template arguments, and calling them

Tags: c++, variadic-templates

I want to create a "grand total" function by summing several other functions together. This can be done at compile time, so I thought a recursive variadic function template would be a good solution. My code so far:

```
int One(){return 1;}
int Two(){return 2;}
int Three(){return 3;}

using func_t = int(void);

//Base case
template <func_t F>
int Total() {
    return F();
}

template <func_t F, func_t... Fs>
int Total() {
    return F() + Total<Fs...>();
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    cout << Total<One, Two, Three>() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

However, I get MSVC compiler error C2668: 'Total': ambiguous call to overloaded function; could be `int Total<int Three(void),>(void)` or `int Total<int Three(void)>(void)`

I don't understand why the compiler has two similar candidates for my function template, the only difference being that one has an extra comma.

Comment: if you can use C++17, you can avoid recursion and, using template folding, simply write `template <func_t ... Fs> int Total () { return (Fs() + ...); }`

Answer (score 2):

Your base case declaration is incorrect, and results in the compiler being unable to differentiate between a call to your base case and a call to your recursive base.

If you make your base case an empty list of templates, there is no longer ambiguity.

```
template <class none = void>
int Total() {
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Of course right after I posted the question I found this same answer in another thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7973827/ambiguous-overload-on-argument-less-variadic-templates?rq=1.

Comment: @Carlton, Shall we close this question as a duplicate?

Comment: Yes, go ahead...